# Can CDATA sections be preserved by BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml, cdata

I'm using BeautifulSoup to read, modify, and write an XML file.  I'm having trouble with CDATA sections being stripped out.  Here's a simplified example.

The culprit XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<foo>
    <bar><![CDATA[
        !@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?,./;'[]\-=
    ]]></bar>
</foo>
```

And here's the Python script.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xmlfile = open("cdata.xml", "r") 
soup = BeautifulSoup( xmlfile, "xml" )
print(soup)
```

Here's the output.  Note the CDATA section tags are missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
<bar>
        !@#$%^&amp;*()_+{}|:"&lt;&gt;?,./;'[]\-=
    </bar>
</foo>
```

I also tried printing `soup.prettify(formatter="xml")` and got the same result with slightly different whitespace.  There isn't much in the docs about reading in CDATA sections, so maybe this is an `lxml` thing?

Is there a way to tell BeautifulSoup to preserve CDATA sections?

*Update* Yes, it's an lxml thing.  http://lxml.de/api.html#cdata  So, the question becomes, is it possible to tell BeautifulSoup to initialize lxml with `strip_cdata=False`?

Comment: This thread suggests there is a bug in lxml affecting this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/beautifulsoup/whLj3jMRq7g

Comment: @BrenBarn The last post does suggest that what I want to do isn't possible, though.  Feel free to post that link as an answer so I can choose it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i grab CData out of BeatuifulSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032172/how-can-i-grab-cdata-out-of-beatuifulsoup)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate.  That question is about how to find/extract CDATA sections.  This one is about how to preserve them when XML is output.  The first is possible, the latter is not.

Answer (score 7):

In my case if I use

```
soup = BeautifulSoup( xmlfile, "lxml-xml" )
```

then cdata is preserved and accesible.

Comment: If you use `lxml-xml`, the `<![CDATA[...]]>` surrounding text is removed and you're left with just the contents. If you want to keep the `<![CDATA[]]>` literal text, you can use `html.parser`.