# how to get content inside CDATA of XML tag django

Tags: python, xml, django

I am using urllib and beautifulsoup to parse xml file in django.
I can't parse the content of description tag with CDATA.

my xml tag.

```
<item>
         <title>EU Confronting US Over Surveillance</title>
    <description><![CDATA[Voice of America is an international news and broadcast organization serving Central and Eastern Europe, the Caucasus, Central Asia, Russia, the Middle East and Balkan countries]]></description>
<guid>http://www.voanews.com/content/eu-confronting-us-over-surveillance/1778928.html</guid>
</item>
```

This description tag is inside the item tag
views.py

```
for i in soup.findAll('item'):
 print i.description.string
```

If CDATA is not there means I can parse the contents inside descirption tag. I don't know how to parse this content.
Please help me out
Also how to get the image inside the tag..

```
<description>&lt;img src='http://static.ibnlive.in.com/ibnlive/pix/sitepix/10_2013/tony-abbott-visits-afghanistan-says-australias-war-is-over_291013013344_338x225.jpg' width='90' height='62'&gt;&lt;p&gt;"Australia's longest war" is ending and its defence forces mission in Afghanistan will be complete by 2013 end, Prime Minister Tony Abbott announced in a statement on Tuesday.&lt;/p&gt;</description>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can CDATA sections be preserved by BeautifulSoup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426507/can-cdata-sections-be-preserved-by-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CData can be accessed like this:

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> txt = '''<description><![CDATA[Voice of America is an international news and broadcast organization serving Central and Eastern Europe, the Caucasus, Central Asia, Russia, the Middle East and Balkan countries]]></description>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(txt)
>>> for cd in soup.findAll(text=True):
...   if isinstance(cd, BeautifulSoup.CData):
...     print 'CData value: %r' % cd
...
CData value: u'Voice of America is an international news and broadcast organi
zation serving Central and Eastern Europe, the Caucasus, Central Asia, Russia, t
he Middle East and Balkan countries'
>>>
```

An edit based on your comment that should help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, CData
import urllib

source_txt = urllib.urlopen("http://voanews.com/api/epiqq")
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(source_txt.read())
for cd in soup.findAll(text=True):
    if isinstance(cd, CData):
        print 'CData value: %r' % cd
```

Things to note:

- The import statement. I'm importing the *entire* BeautifulSoup package
- The `urlopen` parameter. It needs the `http`

Comment: Am parsing news feed. example I took this url "http://www.voanews.com/api/epiqq". In ur code in 3rd line, it shows the following error     AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'read'.  My pared the whole url as sorce_txt=urllib .urlopen("http://www.voanews.c/api/epiqq") b=BeautifulSoup(sorce_txt.read())..... not a particular xml tag. I want to parse the whole url i.e. each and every description tag in that... Give me the suggestion to how to do it Andy

Comment: yes your code is correct Andy... I need how to do it for the whole url.

Comment: I am trying and tell you if I get any error... please guide me at that time Andy

Comment: >>> import urllib
>>> source_txt=urllib.urlopen("http://www.voanews.com/api/epiqq")
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> b=BeautifulSoup(source_txt.read())
>>> for i in b.findAll('item'):
...  for j in i.findAll('description'):
...   for k in j.findAll(text=True):
...    print i
 I didn't get anything.. nothing gets printed.. please help me

Comment: yes Andy you are correct... if it is a single tag means we can define it inside string and parse like you already said... Am parsing an url. The xml file of this url contains more tags like this so I can't give it as a string. In that case how can I parse? Will check it and tell u

Comment: You will need to loop over the `soup` value for each `<item>`

Comment: >>> soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(source_txt.read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute   'BeautifulSoup'    I get this error. I have given like this... from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup