# Using BeautifulSoup to Extract CData

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, cdata

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup from bs4/Python 3 to extract CData. However, whenever I search for it using the following, it returns an empty result. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,CData

txt = '''<foobar>We have
         <![CDATA[some data here]]>
         and more.
         </foobar>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)
for cd in soup.findAll(text=True):
    if isinstance(cd, CData):
        print('CData contents: %r' % cd)
```

Comment: Similar code is found in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032172/how-can-i-grab-cdata-out-of-beautifulsoup), which is where I assume you got this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can CDATA sections be preserved by BeautifulSoup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426507/can-cdata-sections-be-preserved-by-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the default parser doesn't parse CDATA properly. If you specify the correct parser, the CDATA shows up:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt,'html.parser')
```

For more information on parsers, see [the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

I got onto this by using [the diagnose function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#diagnose), which [the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) recommend:

> If you have questions about Beautiful Soup, or run into problems, send mail to the discussion group. If your problem involves parsing an HTML document, be sure to mention what the diagnose() function says about that document.

Using the diagnose() function gives you output of how the different parsers see your html, which enables you to choose the right parser for your use case.

Comment: Yeah, I've used bs4 a bunch in the past, didn't ever catch the diagnose thing. I'm sure it would have saved me time in the past. :)