# How to extract data within a cdata tag using python?

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup, cdata

I used beautiful soup to get CDATA from a html page but i have to extract contents from it and put it in a csv file.

this is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
import csv
f = open('try.html')
ff = csv.writer(open("profiletry.csv", "w"))
ff.writerow(["cdata"]) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(f.readlines()))
cdata = soup.find(text=re.compile("CDATA"))
print(cdata)
ff.writerow([cdata])
newfile = open('cdatatxt.txt','w')
newfile.write(cdata)
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(f.readlines()))
c_data = soup.find(text=re.compile("string"))
print(c_data)
```

If i compile this cdata is printed but i want to get data within it in a key-value pair so that i can store it in a csv file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032172/how-can-i-grab-cdata-out-of-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you.

```
 import re
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
 for x in soup.find_all('item'):
 print re.sub('[\[CDATA\]]', '', x.string)
```

Comment: Should I replace item with cdata according to my code?

Comment: @shahnazshariff did u get the solution?

Comment: import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open('try2.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(f.readlines()))
cdata = soup.find(text=re.compile("CDATA"))
print(cdata)
match = re.search(r'txt: \"\d\"',cdata)
if match:
 print(match.group())
else:
 print('did not find') 

--> used search function instead of sub